# Cassandra aggregation

Tags: cassandra, aggregate-functions, cql

I have a Cassandra cluster with 4 table and data inside.

I want to make request with aggregation function ( sum, max ...) but I've read here that it's impossible :
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_function_r.html

Is there a way to make sum , average, group by, without buying the enterprise version, can I use presto , or other solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aggregate functions will be available as part of Cassandra 3.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4914

Comment: Thanks, i can see no release date, is there a beta that i can use ?

Comment: 4914 is in 2.2-rc1 available on the cassandra downloads page.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it does:

> ## Native aggregates
>
> #### Count
>
> The count function can be used to count the rows returned by a query.
>   Example:
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT (*) FROM plays;
> SELECT COUNT (1) FROM plays;
> ```
>
> It also can be used to count the non null value of a given column:
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT (scores) FROM plays;
> ```
>
> #### Max and Min
>
> The max and min functions can be used to compute the maximum and the
>   minimum value returned by a query for a given column. For instance:
>
> ```
> SELECT MIN (players), MAX (players) FROM plays WHERE game = 'quake';
> ```
>
> #### Sum
>
> The sum function can be used to sum up all the values returned by a
>   query for a given column. For instance:
>
> ```
> SELECT SUM (players) FROM plays;
> ```
>
> #### Avg
>
> The avg function can be used to compute the average of all the values
>   returned by a query for a given column. For instance:
>
> ```
> SELECT AVG (players) FROM plays;
> ```

You can also create your own aggregates, more documentation on aggregates here: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/functions.html?highlight=aggregate